# Change Background opacity without changing content opacity

Tags: .net, wpf, opacity

I wanted to know how can I change the opacity of the background of the WPF Window without effecting the inner child controls. When I change the Window property 'Opacity' to 0.5 I do get a semi-transparent window, but the image inside the window also inherited the 0.5 opacity  value, so how can I just make the opacity for the window only?

Comment: Just subscribing to you're question to see if this is possible, I think it is not, but just in case. Have you tried to set it to color "Transparent" and add, for example, a semi-transparent rectangle which doesn't affect the rest of your objects?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The window is the parent container of everything so setting the opacity on the window will effect everything that it contains. I think what you want to do is change the `Opacity` of the `Window.Background`.

Enabling a window to do transparency involves a couple things to be added. First, you will need to set `Window.AllowsTransparency = True` and also set the `Window.WindowStyle = None`. `WindowStyle.None` creates a window without the minimize, maximize, and close buttons in the window chrome so you'll have to handle that in the application yourself along with resizing and moving the window. After that's all done, then you can set the `Window.Background` to have a brush with an `Opacity` set on it.

The following code sample will show you how to have the window always transparent and set the opacity of the window background to have a different opacity.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="Window"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <!--Window Content-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can always set the window background to transparent if you only want the elements in the window to be visible.

Comment: Im working with style templates. For getting this to work with property setter, I've set the alpha of my background-color to the desired opacity-level and copied the background rgb code to the background setter. :) Works perfectly!

Comment: This is an important nuance, I think. I, too, was setting the control's properties of Background and Opacity. Using the property in this way provides much more control over how embedded controls look and feel.